# xmlHttpRequest.open() (Ajax) -> use a PHP method as "URL"-parameter

Tags: php, ajax, parameters, xmlhttprequest

is it possible to call a `PHP` method (from a class) from within the `xmlHttpRequest.open()`?

```
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET",$class->method, true);
```

Thank you

Comment: not directly no, but create a other php file that call this method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'll have to write a PHP script that loads the class and calls the method.

Comment: **+1**, for the straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link and you will get understand that how ajax works.[Ajax](http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/live-username-availability-checking-using-ajax-and-jquery/)